# Fill dropdownlist from stored procedure Error: was out of range of valid values

Tags: mysql, asp.net, drop-down-menu, controls

For some reason the dropdownlist within my DataGrid gives me the error:

```
Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: index
```

from line:

```
 CType(dgAdmins.Controls(0).Controls(dgAdmins.Controls(0).Controls.Count - 1).Controls(0).FindControl("ddlAddGroup"), DropDownList).DataSource = rdr
```

I've seen this code setup work before so not sure what I am missing. My templateColumn is the 2nd column in the DataGrid.

Vb.net

```
Sub dg_Edit(ByVal s As Object, ByVal e As DataGridCommandEventArgs)
    fillGroups()
End sub

Sub fillGroups()

    Using con2 As New MySqlConnection

        con2.ConnectionString = GetconnString(strFloor, lblDB.Text)

        Dim cmd2 As New MySqlCommand()
        con2.Open()
        cmd2.Connection = con2
        cmd2.CommandText = "stp_Select_GroupNames"

        cmd2.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure

        Dim rdr As MySqlDataReader

        rdr = cmd2.ExecuteReader

        CType(dgAdmins.Controls(0).Controls(dgAdmins.Controls(0).Controls.Count - 1).Controls(0).FindControl("ddlAddGroup"), DropDownList).DataSource = rdr
        CType(dgAdmins.Controls(0).Controls(dgAdmins.Controls(0).Controls.Count - 1).Controls(0).FindControl("ddlAddGroup"), DropDownList).DataValueField = "ID"
        CType(dgAdmins.Controls(0).Controls(dgAdmins.Controls(0).Controls.Count - 1).Controls(0).FindControl("ddlAddGroup"), DropDownList).DataTextField = "GroupName"
        CType(dgAdmins.Controls(0).Controls(dgAdmins.Controls(0).Controls.Count - 1).Controls(0).FindControl("ddlAddGroup"), DropDownList).DataBind()
        rdr.Close()
        con2.Close()
    End Using
End sub
```

ASP.net

```
<asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="'Group'" ItemStyle-Width="225" FooterStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
         <FooterTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAddGroup" runat="server" />
         </FooterTemplate>
         <ItemTemplate>
             <%#Container.DataItem("GroupName")%>
         </ItemTemplate>
         <EditItemTemplate>
             <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEditGroup" runat="server" />
          </EditItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateColumn>
```

Update

Stored procedure

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `stp_Select_GroupNames`()
BEGIN
SELECT ID, GroupName from tblg;
END
```

When I run a dataset off the stored procedure I return a count so I know I am getting records returned as well.

Comment: Is there data for that dropdown list? My first thought is that there is no data and the -1 would cause the error.

Comment: Also, can you show your stored procedure?

Comment: Show the whole grid markup. If you put a breakpoint on your offending line, what is the value of dgAdmins.Controls(0).Controls.Count ?

Comment: @mjw count is 4

Comment: added stored procedure @WEI_DBA

Comment: Please show the markup for the entire grid. Also, show where you're doing the dropdown databinding code you've labeled above as "vb.net" - where in code behind?

Comment: So if I do `Dim dd As DropDownList = CType(dgAdmins.Controls(0).Controls(1).FindControl("ddlAddGroup"), DropDownList)` and specify the column inside `Controls()` it works ... hmm

Comment: @mjw got it to work with specifying the column control. not sure why I had to tho. I also updated the values above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current workaround:

So to fill footer you use:

```
Sub fillAddGroups()
    Dim ds As DataSet = getGroups()
    Dim dd As DropDownList = CType(dgAdmins.Controls(0).Controls(dgAdmins.Controls(0).Controls.Count - 1).Controls(0).FindControl("ddlAddGroup"), DropDownList)
    dd.DataSource = ds
    dd.DataValueField = "ID"
    dd.DataTextField = "GroupName"
    dd.DataBind()
End Sub
```

To fill dropdown that shows after clicking the edit button you do:

```
Sub dg_Edit(ByVal s As Object, ByVal e As DataGridCommandEventArgs)
    Dim intempId As Integer
    Dim strGroup As String = ""
    intempId = CType(e.Item.Cells(0).FindControl("lblEmployeeNumber"), Label).Text
    strGroup = CType(e.Item.Cells(0).FindControl("lblGroup"), Label).Text
    dgAdmins.EditItemIndex = e.Item.ItemIndex
    sdsGroups.ConnectionString = GetconnString(strF, lblDB.Text)
    ShowEmpTable(intempId)
    fillAddGroups()
End Sub
```

where sdsGroups is a SqlDataSource in HTML:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsGroups"
               ProviderName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" SelectCommand="stp_Select_FloortblGroupNames" runat="server" />
```

Gridview modifications

```
<asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="'Group'" ItemStyle-Width="225" FooterStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
      <FooterTemplate>
          <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAddGroup" runat="server" />
            </FooterTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                   <asp:Label ID="lblGroup" Text='<%#Container.DataItem("GroupName")%>' runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
             <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEditGroup" runat="server" DataSourceID="sdsGroups" DataTextField="GroupName" DataValueField="ID"/>
              </EditItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateColumn>
```

Comment: Your column indexes aren't close to what you have in the original question fwiw. Glad you got it working

Comment: @mjw I did some tweaking to try and find issue. The original code was actually trying to grab the footer only not the edit row.

Comment: touchy but figured it out :)